# Can I delete rows from catalog_product_entity_decimal

Tags: magento-1.9, database, product-prices

I have strange problem with Magento. Our price attribute is set as GLOBAL, so product price is same in every store we have. Or at least it should be. Somehow with some products it is not like that. If I try to change price for those "broken products" it chances only at "default" store view but not from others. I cannot change price for other storeview from magento admin. But I can change it directly from table catalog_product_entity_decimal. I found out that for most products there is only single line for `attribute_id` 75 (=price) in catalog_product_entity_decimal, but for those "broken" products there is line (and price value) for every store.

So can I just delete those additional lines (using Sequel pro) and leave only the original line?

Answer (score 3):

Whatever you do, back up your db first.
And yes, you can delete all the rows and keep the ones that have `store_id = 0`.

So this query should solve your problem:

```
DELETE FROM 
     catalog_product_entity_decimal
WHERE
     attribute_id = 75 AND
     store_id <> 0
```

But in case I wasn't specific the first time, backup your database.
Clear the cache and rebuild the indexes when you are done.

Comment: I had the same needs (and I applied the response from Marius). Should be mark as anwered.